# Python heroku -app not compatible with buildpack

Tags: python, heroku

I read all the previous posts about it but still couldn't correct it. I added requirements.txt and Procfile in the directory in my computer created by Heroku. Procfile reads "web: python Chat Server.py". Also added runtime.txt in the same directory that reads "python-3.6.2".However, it keeps giving the same error again in the command prompt. How can I solve this? This is the entire error message:

"C:\Users\asus\chat_server>git push heroku master
Counting objects: 6, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (4/4), done.
Writing objects: 100% (6/6), 1.14 KiB | 585.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 6 (delta 1), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote:
remote: -----> App not compatible with buildpack: https://codon-buildpacks.s3.amazonaws.com/buildpacks/heroku/python.tgz
remote:        More info: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks#detection-failure
remote:
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote:
remote: !       Push rejected to boiling-stream-15219.
remote:
To https://git.heroku.com/boiling-stream-15219.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/boiling-stream-15219.git' "

Comment: What error are you getting while build is ran ?

Comment: "App not compatible with buildpack:  https://codon-buildpacks.s3.amazonaws.com/buildpacks/heroku/python.tgz"

Comment: I edited my post so that the entire error message can be seen.

Comment: Ensure that you have done `git add requirements.txt Procfile` and `git commit`, before pushing to heroku.

Comment: Thank you so much ! It worked ! However, after I deployed, it gave "an application error". But I guess it's because of my code. There were some variables I didn't set properly. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 9):

Anyone reading this: you'll need two files:

First file:
`requirements.txt` containing something like:
`gunicorn==19.7.1`
or whatever the results of `pip freeze > requirements.txt` are.

Second file:
`Procfile` containing something like:
`web: gunicorn app:app`
or potentially blank. Note that `app:app` in this example is a reference to your python filename. It means that every time a `web` process is declared, and a dyno of this type is started, also run the command `gunicorn app:app` to start your web server.

Then `git add .` and `git commit -m "added Procfile and requirements.txt"`.

Then run `git push heroku master` to push from your local `master` branch to the `heroku` remote.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to JaredH's answer, make sure that your current branch is master before you run `git push heroku master`.

Comment: <thumbs-up.gif>