# Python 3.7.0 Heroku buildpack issue

Tags: python, tensorflow, flask, heroku, buildpack

I've read some people with the same issue, but nothing suggested has worked. I'm trying to deploy a silly project to Heroku but nothing is working.

Below this lines you can see the message:

> Writing objects: 100% (100/100), 55.42 MiB | 625.00 KiB/s, done.
> Total 100 (delta 19), reused 4 (delta 0) remote: Compressing source
> files... done. remote: Building source:
>
> Counting objects: 100, done. Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
> Compressing objects: 100% (94/94), done. Writing objects: 100%
> (100/100), 55.42 MiB | 625.00 KiB/s, done. Total 100 (delta 19),
> reused 4 (delta 0) remote: Compressing source files... done.
>
> App not compatible with buildpack:
> https://buildpack-registry.s3.amazonaws.com/buildpacks/heroku/python.tgz
> !     Push failed

This is my github repository, just in case someone wants to see the code:
[Pets vs Dogs](https://github.com/exequielmoneva/cats-vs-dogs)

Comment: _Specifically_, what have you read about this issue, and what have you tried? Do you have a `requirements.txt` file or `Pipfile` and `Pipfile.lock` in the root directory of your repository? It doesn't look like it, and surely that must be the most common issue for this error message. Move your `requirements.txt` up a directory, commit, and deploy again.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python heroku -app not compatible with buildpack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48341454/python-heroku-app-not-compatible-with-buildpack)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UPDATE: the problem was the structure itself. I had to place the requirements.txt and Procfile at the root directory.