# Buildpack error when proper buildpack is already installed

Tags: python, django, heroku, deployment

I'm trying to Deploy to heroku on my django app, but I'm receiving an error saying:

```
remote: -----> App not compatible with buildpack: https://buildpack-registry.s3.amazonaws.com/buildpacks/heroku/python.tgz
remote:        More info: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks#detection-failure
```

however I'm running the correct build pack as far as I can see:

```
(virtual) MacBook-Pro-de-Stephen:src stephenlang$ heroku buildpacks
=== programatic-learning Buildpack URL
heroku/python
```

Could it be the way I have my files structured?

[image]

Procfile:
web: gunicorn blog.wsgi --log-file -

runtime.txt:
python-3.8.5

Is there something I'm missing with regards to deployment?

Comment: Your `requirements.txt`, `Procfile`, and `runtime.txt` should all be in the root of your repository. Move them there, commit, and redeploy.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python 3.7.0 Heroku buildpack issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62962527/python-3-7-0-heroku-buildpack-issue)